# Joi required 2 input validation

Tags: reactjs, joi

I want to validate a currency entry that has only two fields (currency and info). currency is number and text field input is string. If the currency is different from 0.00, the information must be mandatory. When currency (expenseAnaliz) is different "0.00" my validation works correctly, when currency is 0.00 it shouldn't validate but when it is 0,00 it validates

```
expenseAnaliz:Joi.number()
             .when('expenseInfoAnaliz',{is:Joi.number(),
                                        then: Joi.number().allow(0.00),
                                        otherwise:Joi.number().required().label('Analiz Harcama Detayı')}),
expenseInfoAnaliz:Joi.string().allow(null),
```

Comment: what's a problem?

Comment: I want no validation when value is 0,00 @A.R.SEIF